# RxJava - Chained calls

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have two method. Let it see the first one's model.

```
open class CommentModel {
    var postid: String? = null
    var ownerid: String? = null
    var created: Date? = null
    var message: String? = null

    constructor() {
    }

    constructor(postid: String?, ownerid: String?, message: String?, created: Date?) {
        this.ownerid = ownerid
        this.created = created
        this.postid = postid
        this.message = message
    }
}
```

In this model. I have ownerid. I need to start a new call to get the owner's UserModel.

So:

```
   commentRepository.getPostCommentsById(postId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    { commentModel ->
                    // it = the owner of comment.
                        userRepository.getUserDetailsByUid(commentModel.ownerid!!)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .subscribe(
                                        { userModel ->
                                            val comment = CommentWithOwnerModel(commentModel,usermodel)
                                            view.loadComment(comment)
                                        },
                                        {
                                        }
                                )
                    },
                    {
                        view.errorOnCommentsLoading()
                    }
            )
```

How can I use RXJava in chain?
There is any good practice to do it?  Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: if you do it this way you'll be dependent on RxJava to gather your data rather than your code using RxJava as a helper. I'm not sure you want to chain methods like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the [`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) operator:

```
 commentRepository.getPostCommentsById(postId)
            .flatMap { commentModel ->
                        userRepository.getUserDetailsByUid(commentModel.ownerid!!)
                            .map { userModel -> CommentWithOwnerModel(commentModel,usermodel) }
            }
            .subscribeOn(...)
            .observeOn(...)
            .subscribe(
                { view.loadComment(it) },
                { view.errorOnCommentsLoading() }
            )
```

You can do it a bit more verbose (and easier to understand) with the [`share`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/refcount.html) operator:

```
val commentObs = commentRepository.getPostCommentsById(postId).share()
val userObs = commentObs.flatMap { userRepository.getUserDetailsByUid(it.ownerid!!) }
val commentWithOwnerObs = Single.zip(commentObs, userObs,
    // Not using any IDE so this line may not compile as is :S
    { comment, user -> CommentWithOwnerModel(comment, user) } )
commentWithOwnerObs
    .subscribeOn(...)
    .observeOn(...)
    .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Check the updated answer. You can get a similar result but with an easier to understand code by using `share`

Comment: Ah! Really. Thank you :)

Comment: Yea. IDE can't compile it.

Comment: Well, that'll prevent you from copy&pasting and using the code without understanding it first ;)

Comment: I saw your comment :) That's why I wrote "Yea"